# Read xml through sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

I have passed the xml string to the stored procedure and need to insert that xml values to the sql database table. Below is the script

```
Declare @tab1 table(id int , name varchar(20),Salary int)
declare @xml xml

set @xml = '<Models>
               <Model_Id ID="54">
                   <Data>
                       <Name>Nandani</Name>
                       <Salary>1000</Salary>
                   </Data>
                   <Data>
                       <Name>Amit</Name>
                       <Salary>5000</Salary>
                   </Data>
               </Model_Id>
               <Model_Id ID="55">
                   <Data>
                   <Name>Pankaj</Name>
                   <Salary>2000</Salary>
                   </Data>
               </Model_Id>
           </Models>'

insert into @tab1(id, name, Salary) 
   SELECT 
      doc.col.value('(Model_Id/@ID)[1]', 'INT'),
      doc.col.value('(Model_Id/Data/Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),    
      doc.col.value('(Model_Id/Data/Salary)[1]','Varchar(50)')
```

But it is inserting only one record into that table, however there should be 3 record in the table. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO @tab1(id, name, Salary) 
   SELECT 
      xc.value('(../@ID)[1]', 'INT'),
      xc.value('(Name)[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'),    
      xc.value('(Salary)[1]','Varchar(50)')   
   FROM
      @xml.nodes('/Models//Model_Id//Data') AS XT(XC)
```

With the call to `.nodes()`, you're getting back a "pseudo" table of XML fragments, one for each of the XML elements specified by the XPath expression. Then you apply the `.value()` call to each of those XML fragments to pull out the individual attribute and element values.